# Dropdown Menu Load On Select, Not Page Load

Tags: javascript, iframe, dropdown

I have the following page with 2 dropdown filters. When the user selects and option in dropdown 1, a list of hundreds of options under dropdown 2 appear for the user to select. While this solution works, the page load takes very load upon first visit.

Is there a way for the iframes to load upon the user selecting an option in the dropdown rather than all the iframes loading all at once when the page loads?

Here's a JSFiddle. Any help would really be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/wp9ke0td

Thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).children("option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "catlist") {
        $(".queuelist").hide();
        $(".agentlist").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".catlist").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "queuelist") {
        $(".agentlist").hide();
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".queuelist").show();
        $(".queuelist select").change();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "agentlist") {
        $(".queuelist").hide();
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".agentlist").show();
        $(".agentlist select").change();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "MPFUC") {
      console.log("FUC");
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".MPFUC").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "MPFLC") {
      console.log("FlC");
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".MPFLC").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "claire") {
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".claire").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "darren") {
        $(".agentcard").hide();
        $(".queuecard").hide();
        $(".darren").show();
      }

    });
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: What about load content on ajax call?

Comment: So I'm relatively new at this. Would you be able to help with some code by any chance?

Comment: I suggest you need to try it by your self. It is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to increase speed of your script:

1. load child select data on main select changed using ajax.

   Even more, you can firstly load and render page. After it is all loaded then initiate to load (using ajax) main select options, or you can load main select options after user clicks on it.
2. use vanillaJS instead of jquery, you will be surprised how fasted is it.

Comment: So I'm relatively new at this. Would you be able to help with some code by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmobyg1f/5/)

**Step 1:** Save your options data in key value lists.

```
var categoryList = [{key: -1, value: 'Select Category...'}, {key: 'work', value: 'Work Queues'}, {key: 'agent', value: 'Agents'}];
var workList = [{key: -1, value: 'Select Queue...'}, {key: 'google.someurl.com', value: 'Google'}, {key: 'yahoo.someurl.com', value: 'Yahoo'}];
var agentList = [{key: -1, value: 'Select Agent...'}, {key: 'claire.someurl.com', value: 'Claire'}, {key: 'darren.someurl.com', value: 'Darren'}];

var keyValueLists = {
  category: categoryList,
  work: workList,
  agent: agentList,
}
```

**Step 2:** 
Set your select options by code (using key value lists).

```
function setSelect(queryString, listName){
  var element = $(queryString);
  element.empty();

  if(!listName || listName.length <= 0){
    element.hide();
  }else{
    getKeyValueList(listName, function(list){
      for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        var l = list[i];
        element.append( $('<option></option>').attr("value",l.key).text(l.value) );
      }
      element.show();
      console.log('setting select: ' + queryString, list);
    });
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** Fetch key value lists if you do not already have them cached.

```
function getKeyValueList(name, callback){
  if(!keyValueLists.hasOwnProperty(name)){//if true, keyValue list is not chached
  //fetch keyValueList with ajax
  //cache list -> add as property on keyValueLists
  //callback(keyValueLists[name]);
  }else{
    callback(keyValueLists[name]);
  }
}
```

**Step 4:** Set url of Iframe.

```
function setIframe(url){
  var element = $('iframe.someiframe');
  if(!url){
    element.hide();
  }else{
    element.show();
    element.attr('src', url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a really helpful starting point :) As I'm such a noobie at this, could you possibly provide a few examples of results as I'm really new at this. For example, when i select Claire or Darren, how do i show an iframe? In my early build, i have options like this: <option value="claire">Claire</option>. Where would these go?

Comment: This line `$('<option></option>').attr("value",l.key).text(l.value)` does that.
Key could be anything, lets say 'claire'. And Value could be anything, lets say 'Claire'.  Think of key as the id and value as display name.

In the onchange event of the second select, I get the value from both of them and you can use that to set the url of an iframe to whatever you like.

`$('iframe.someclass').attr('src', 'http://someurl.com')`

Comment: In the example take a look in the console. I log every time something interesting happens.

Comment: If this answer was useful pls up-vote or mark as correct.